# VBA Macro to retrieve information from a google header after a search

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that will go into google to search for the county of several cities. So far I have managed to make the macro search for the correct terms but the only roadblock I have is when I get the results. I don't know what to write to retrieve them.

When I do the search I get this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8jEh.png

What I want to do is retrieve the "Suffolk County" line but I am at lost on how to do that.

Does anybody have any tips or know how to do this or what to look for? I already tried inspecting the item but to no avail.

This is how my code looks so far:

```
Sub AutomateIE()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim City As String
    Dim State As String
    Dim URL As String

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    'For testing Purposes
    City = "boston"
    State = "MA"

     'Search google for state and county
     URL = "www.google.com/?safe=active&ssui=on#q=" + City + "+" + State + "+county&safe=active&ssui=on"
    ie.Navigate URL

     'Loop unitl ie page is fully loaded
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to make sure the "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft Internet Controls" are available.  In the VB Window, go to Tools -> References, and put a check mark by that library (may have to scroll to find it).

Try this:

```
Sub test()
Dim IE      As New InternetExplorer
Dim city$, state$

'For testing Purposes
city = "boston"
state = "MA"

 'Search google for state and county
URL = "www.google.com/?safe=active&ssui=on#q=" + city + "+" + state + "+county&safe=active&ssui=on"

IE.navigate URL
IE.Visible = False
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016")) ' For internal page refresh or loading

Dim doc     As HTMLDocument  'variable for document or data which need to be extracted out of webpage
Set doc = IE.document
Dim dd      As Variant
dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("_eF")(0).innerText
' Now, trim the name to take the State out
dd = Left(dd, WorksheetFunction.Search(",", dd) - 1)
MsgBox dd
End Sub
```

Comment: What reference does the HTMLDocument  come from?

Comment: Ah, sorry - I believe from the "Microsoft HTML Object Library".

Comment: That is it. I get an object variabl or with block not set error at dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("_eF")(0).innerText but then that line runs after a few seconds of waiting in debug.  Could it be a timming issue?

Comment: It could be - I'm still pretty new to HTML parsing, but I did remove a line that had the script wait some time. I'll update my code with that to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Bruce! Thanks for this, I am currently running into a Compile Error: User-defined error type not defined. This comes up on the first line of code the Dim IE      As New InternetExplorer any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @MijailMontero - Ah, sorry. I updated my post, you'll also need "Microsoft Internet Controls".  That should do it.

Comment: @MijailMontero - if this works for you, do you mind marking as answer?  Glad to help!